# What is the proper way to change the section title font in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, titlesec

Suppose I wanted to use a different font for a title then the body text in LaTeX (pdflatex). (For example, if I wanted to use a slightly fancier font for titles, or a sans-serif one.) How would I do that, change the font of a class of thing throughout the document, in a proper way. (Likewise, if I wanted to change the document title, captions, etc. Is there a general way of doing this?)

Comment: ``ln `which xelatex` `which pdflatex` ``

Comment: @SeanAllred Why?

Comment: @cfr Sorry about that – that kind of snark was the effect of two-years-expired cough syrup that I unwittingly took… My point was that there is little reason that I can think of to stick to pdftex *especially* when you want to do fancy things with your fonts.

Comment: @SeanAllred I don't really agree, but my main point was that it wouldn't even work.

Comment: @SeanAllred I don't use other engines, since then I'll learn features I can't use when submitting to journals. If I only ever use PDFlatex I won't have that problem.

Comment: @cfr I never said I made any sense :) Sorry for the general confusion. Canageek, that's a fair point – I never considered that. It's my understanding though that journals will enforce their style to a tee – such customizations as this are generally for nought. But that's probably a discussion for chat :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The titlesec or sectsty packages are your friends for the standard classes. If you want some more control, try the komascript classes or memoir. See [the UKTeXFAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-secthead).

Comment: I suggest you broaden you answer by giving some code.

Comment: The OP made a rather broad question, so the broad general answer.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that really much depends on what you are trying to
achieve.

Do you want to make a class that others can use as well? You can
define your own commands for sectioning. Are there just minor
changes within one of your documents? Use package `etoolbox` and
patch your changes. Are there bigger changes to the sectioning
and titles? Package `titlesec` is commonly used with the standard
classes.

KOMA-classes have their own way of defining the font for various
instances of a document. The following example shows the
interface.

> Disclaimer: This is just for demonstration, nobody should use
>   that many stuff in just one document.

[image: canageekTitleFonts]

```
\documentclass[plainheadsepline,headsepline=2pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[font={\Huge\fontfamily{qhv}}]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[font={\rmfamily\footnotesize\itshape}]{section}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\usefont{T1}{qzc}{m}{it}}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\color{red!80!black}}
\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{red!80!black}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{lazy Leguan}
\section{walzing wombat}
\captionof{figure}{A figure caption}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```